# Find an item in vector created by own StringTokenizer

Tags: c++

I have made my own StringTokenizer class:

```
class StringTokenizer {
private:
    vector<string> tokens; //output
    string strIn;          //input
public:
    StringTokenizer(string strIn) {
        this->strIn = strIn;

        string str(strIn);
        string tmpstr;
        stringstream ss(str);

        while(ss >> tmpstr)
            tokens.push_back(tmpstr);
    }

    vector<string> getTokens() {
        return tokens;
    }
}
```

I have my main function

```
int main() {
    string str = "a b c d";
    StringTokenizer st(str);

    if(find(st.getTokens().begin(), st.getTokens().end(), item) != st.getTokens().end()) {
        cout << "found";
    } else {
        cout << "not found";
    }
}
```

When function is returning true, everything is working fine. Otherwise program is crashing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have UB, `getTokens()` returns a vector by *value* and you call that twice (once for begin, once for end) which means your two iterators dont point to the same container.

Comment: @Borgleader what is UB?

Comment: @P.Musiał - UB is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: I have created a new vector: vector<string> vec = st.getTokens(); and it's working. I don't know exactly why but thanks a lot :)

Comment: @P.Musiał comparing iterators that point to different containers (which you get by returning multiple copies)  is not well defined. That's your problem.

Comment: Undefined behavior is something that'll take some time to wrap your head around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour in your code, `getTokens()` returns a vector by *value* and you call that twice (once for `begin()`, once for `end()`) which means your two iterators don't point to the same container. This just cannot work. And then, you call it a *third* time to compare the result of `find` which is also incorrect for the same reason.

You can easily fix this by changing it to be:

```
auto tokens = st.getTokens();
if(find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), item) != tokens.end())
```

or you can return `const vector<string>&` from `getTokens()`.